# Jquery ajax call cross origin jsonp

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to make a cross domain call using jquery $ajax

```
         $.ajax({
          url: 'http://test.com:8261/service',
          cache: 'true',
          data: {
            "method" : "getClient"
          },
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          jsonp: false,
          jsonpCallback: "callBack",
          type: "GET",
          success:function(successData){
            console.log("Success");
                console.log(successData);
            },
          error: function(errorData){
            console.log("Error");
            console.log(errorData);
            }
        });
```

Getting below error after call is made and it goes to error event.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

### Edit

Error as posted in comments:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "test.com:8261/service ?callback=callBack&method=getClient&_=1429693676570".n.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.min.js:4n.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js: admin?callback=callBack&method=getClient&_=1429693676570:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Comment: Please post full stacktrace and not just a part of the error.

Comment: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://test.com:8261/service
 ?callback=callBack&method=getClient&_=1429693676570".n.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.min.js:4n.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:
admin?callback=callBack&method=getClient&_=1429693676570:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment